# I can't see the vertices in vertex mode

Tags: mesh

Though I am in vertex select mode, I am unable to see the vertices as shown.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Your viewport overlay is turned off. Upper right corner, the icon with two circles is grey :).

Answer (score 1):

Your viewport overlay is turned off.
Upper right corner, the icon with two circles is grey :).

[image]